# Is this scheme- An Ip camera network completely isolated from rest of Intranet

Tags: switch, ip, power-over-ethernet

IP camera network  completely isolated from rest of the Intranet work and for connecting each IP camera  at mutually 900 m TO 1.5 km distanc to switch near NVR about 800 to 1.5 km from each IP camera away is 4 core SM OS2 OFC ok or 12/6 core  SM OS2 OFC is needed and how will the OFC terminate and will be justification for using each of 4 cor,6 core and 12 core single mode OS2 OFC from camera to to the un mamanaged switch near NVR and from that switch to each of the four or 5 client machines again 800 to 1.5 km from the NVR switch location More specifically it is Total 10 to 15 IP cameras each located at remote sites 800 m to 1.5 Km from  NVR location  patch panel  which are then connected  to the 24 port unmanaged switch with duplex fiber connector and SFP module; This subnet or LAN will be completely isolated from rest of the existing Intranet. Authorized personnel will access the Ip cameras and NVR channels for viewing or administrative purpose. Their client computers will have two NIC cards one configured for existing Intranet/Internet and another NIC with network configuration of camera network.when viewing cameras they will disable the Intranet NIC and for each  such client use there has to be new  direct OFC  link from client computer for viewing IP camera & managing cameras & NVR  to NVR cum 24 port unmanaged network switch  location.Such users will be given username password & role authorization for this by Ip camera NVR software system

As a novice also want to know what is use of the 12 cores of single mode OS2 OFC. or should I use 4 core or 6 core What is the optimum no of cores in this hypothetical scenario what is justification for regarding that number of core as optimum and on what factors other than mechanical strength is to be taken in to account while selecting the no of core because and picture quality is most important the video captured by the camera should get to the viewers as soon
 as possible almost in realtime  without any jitter or loss also taking into account the cost factor so some trade off can be allowed between speed quality and expenditure to be borne for buying high quality OFC that may not be needed hereand get store in the NVR  Will each core be terminated with a pigtail LC connector to fiber distribution box also known as fiber patch panel, and then to fiber termination box, and from there fiber core will be spliced with another duplex LC connector to the 12 SFP ports of the 24 port un-managed ethernet switch via 12 single mode SFP modules? 12 SFP ports through the 12 cores of same single continuous OS2 SM fiber and the the 12 cores will end at a fiber distribution box also known as light guide interconnect unit or fiber patch panel by splicing with duplex LC pigtails and from there via 12 LC LC patch cords to fiber termination box and from via 12 duplex LC -SC patch cable will connect to 12 SFP ports of the ethernet switch. This scheme will be followed for connecting two buildings separated by say 800 m to 1 or 1.5 km, but having computers belonging to the same subnet as all computers in the local intranet are part of 1 subnet.
I came out with this plan as no one answered my question and hypothetical situation demands that the IP camera LAN should be completely isolated from the existing Intranet so the plan in brief is this 10 to 15 IP cameras to be installed at different remote sites 800 m to 1.5 Km from  NVR location fiber  patch panel; cameras  terminate by OFC link to this LIU/fiber patch panel  & from the patch panel they are connected  to the 24 port unmanaged switch with duplex fiber connector and SFP module;  This subnet or LAN will be completely isolated from rest of the existing Intranet. Authorized personnel will access the IP cameras and NVR channels for viewing or administrative purpose. Their client computers will have two NIC cards one configured for existing Intranet/Internet and another NIC with network configuration of camera network.when viewing cameras they will disable the Intranet NIC and for each  such client use there has to be new  direct OFC  link from client computer for viewing IP camera & managing cameras & NVR of say 8/16/24 TB storage to NVR cum 24 port unmanaged network switch  location.Such users will be given username password & role authorization for this by Ip camera NVR software system Port number of switch may be more in view of more clients mor future IP cameras and also for sake of redundancy sothe description of the Intranet becomes irrelevant and Layer 3 switch ; load balancer ;UTM;firewall are irrelevent in this context I approached the problem in a wrong manner and started describing the Intranet infrastructure I want to know can I use 2 core single mode OS2 OFC for this purpose or should I use 4 core,6 core or 12 core single OS2 OFC for this purpose and how to terminate the OFC at the camera end and the switch end

I think that I can use a 4 core SM OS2 in place of 12 core SM OS2 OFC for connecting each camera to the NVR connected switch required for this. At each remote site since there is going to be one IP camera powered by PoE how to interface each IP camera with 4 core or 12 core OS2 SM OFC. I don't think that for connecting each remotely located IP camera to the NVR site multi core SM OS2 OFC is needed. Simple SM OS2 OFC should be enough may be 4 core for redundancy dothe multiple cores have any role in this use case scenario.
As advised by the respected editors I am not asking about specifications Sir but I would very much thankful to you if you please explain the thing for example I understand that a single core single mode OFC has 1 fiber for sending and 1 fiber for receiving data exclusively and multi cor thus means multiple such single mode single core OFC packed as one Now for sending data that is video and audio and controlling the camera the high definition IP camera will have RJ45 port i will search for the model the CAT6 cable will carry data as well as power from the PoE port of an network switch which should not be 300 ft away from IP cam Now there will be a SFP port in the same switch and with an SFP module with a duplex LC connector I will need a fiber optic termination box where 4 core single mode OS2 OFC has been terminated only one core will be terminated 1 by splicing with LC duplex pigtail for 1 IP camera other core are redundant here and then the 4 core armoured cable is laid underground for about 800 meters to 1 km to reach the place where the NVR is placed along with a 24 port unmanaged ethernet for 15 such remote cameras and the switch will be having above 15 SFP port for OFC interfacing and connecting to 15 such 4 core single mode OS2 OFC arriving and as in the NVR site 15 different OFC are arriving from 15 remote locations so there should a fiber patch panel where the 15 OFC will be terminated by splicing and from there 15 duplex LC connector the 15 OFCs will send data through 15 SFP modules through 15 SFP ports of the ethernet switch having high fabric value and from the switch a CAT6 cable will enter the NVR. All IP cameras and NVR and this ethernet switch will form an isolated LAN. users in another LAN with camera and NVR password will view camera /NVR.Layer 3 switch 2 join the 2 LANs .Please let me know if this scheme is wrong and the parts I am having confusion with like Fiber termination.Please ignore all specification .Please help and guide me by helping me to find if my concept or idea of the thing is right or wrong.If inadvertently by mistake any where specifications have been mentioned or requested please ignore that but help me with your expert knowledge and expertise is the conceptor idea or plan workable right or wrong or what corrections will be required.~~~~

Comment: Please Sir lift the hold as offtopic as I have edited the question and please help me with your knowledge I cannot find anywhere on the net what purpose the individual cores of the multi single mode OFC serve what is use of multi-core i guess trwo long distance ethernet switch's SFP ports coomunicate by each core of a single SFP so for 24 port switch with say 12 SFP ports can communicate with another such 24 port switch with 1

Comment: 12 SFP ports  through the 12 cores of same single continuous OS2  SM fiber  and the the 12 cores will end at a fiber distribution box also known as light guide interconnect unit or fiber patch panel by splicing with duplex LC pigtails and from there via 12 LC LC patch cords to fiber termination box and from via 12 duplex LC -SC patch cable will connect to 12 SFP ports of the ethernet switch.This scheme will be followed for connecting two buildings separated by say 800m to1 or 1.5 km  but having computers belonging to the same subnet as all computers in the local intranet are part of 1 subnet.

Comment: With 12 fiber cores, you will have six SFP connections because each SFP needs two fibers (Tx and Rx).

Comment: Also, PoE plays no part in fiber. That would be on copper connections of <= 100 meters.

Comment: Please do not ask about specifications for the equipment as that is off-topic here. We simply cannot recommend equipment, and you know that you need a switch with multiple SFP connections and the proper SFPs. The cameras will not have fiber connections, so you will need switches at the remote ends, too. Also, end-devices, such as the cameras and NVR are off-topic here. Also, do not keep repeating the poorly formatted text that duplicates what is already in the question.

Comment: I am not asking about specifications Sir but I would very much thankful to you if you please explain the thing for example I understand that a single core single mode OFC has 1 fiber for sending and 1 fiber for receiving data exclusively and multi cor thus means multiple such single mode single core OFC packed as one Now for sending data that is video and audio and controlling the camera the high definition IP camera will have  RJ45 port i will search for the model the CAT6 cable will carry data as well as power from the PoE port of an network switch which should not be 300 ft away from IP cam

Comment: Now there will be a SFP port in the same switch and with an SFP module with a duplex LC connector I will need a fiber optic termination box where 4 core single mode OS2 OFC has been terminated only one core will be terminated 1 by splicing with LC duplex pigtail for 1 IP camera other core are redundant here and then the 4 core armoured cable is laid underground for about 800 meters to 1 km to reach the place where the NVR is placed along with a 24 port unmanaged ethernet for 15 such remote cameras and the switch will be having above 15 SFP port for OFC interfacing and connecting to

Comment: 15 such 4 core single mode OS2 OFC arriving and as in the NVR site 15 different OFC are arriving from 15 remote locations so there should a fiber patch panel where the 15 OFC will be terminated by splicing and from there 15 duplex LC connector the 15 OFCs will send data through 15 SFP modules through 15 SFP ports of the ethernet switch having high fabric value and from the switch a CAT6 cable will enter the NVR.All IP cameras and  NVR and this ethernet switch will form an isolated LAN. users in another LAN   with camera and NVR password will view camera /NVR.Layer 3 switch 2 join the 2 LANs .

Comment: "_I understand that a single core single mode OFC has 1 fiber for sending and 1 fiber for receiving_" No, that is incorrect. That means that there is a single fiber, not a pair of fibers. A 12-core means that you have 12 fibers, and, in most cases, that would be enough for six links (one Tx and one Rx per link). See [this image](http://www.olsontech.com/mr_fiber/images/Fiber_Buffer.gif). A core is a single fiber. Unless you use the BX fiber standard, then a single core can only be used for a single direction, and you need two cores for each link.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

Just to amplify ZAC and Ron's comments:

1. The cost of the fiber is a small part of the cost of installing fiber.  The labor to dig, terminate, etc far exceeds the cost of the cable itself.  Therefore it makes sense to pull multicore cable even if you are only going to use 1 or 2 pairs today.  You may have future needs.
2. You only need two cores (two fiber strands) to connect each camera. The other cores are only for future use, and have no affect on your video performance.
3. You will have to supply a switch at each location for PoE.  The camera will have a copper RJ45 connector which will connect to the PoE switch.  The fiber will also connect to the switch.
4. If you assign your cameras and computers (on the second NIC card) private IP addresses, you will have effectively isolated the cameras from the Internet.  You do not need to disable the Internet NICs on your PCs.  They will choose the correct NIC automatically.
5. Your question is very difficult to read.  It's long and wandering, and I'm sure many readers simply give up before finishing.  Please consider editing your question to the salient points -- you will get many more responses that way.

Comment: Many a thank tou you for stopping by and helping me will you please explain me how single mode OS2 multicore OFC terminate in the switch and ethernet that is exactly how via pig tail or duplex connector the interfacing through SFP module from OFC to ethernet is done what is physics engineering and practical reasons for doing and is the fiber SFP module an alternative to media converter.Infact I have rewritten the question and I will do it again

Answer (score 0):

For a 1 km link over OS2 fiber you can use `100BASE-FX` (up to 2 km) or (preferrably) `1000BASE-LX` transceivers (up to 10 km).

These use fibers in pairs, so you could run six links over a 12-core fiber. If the fiber count is an issue you can use `1000BASE-BX` with single fiber links for up to twelve links (up to 10 km).

You can use a switch to "split" a link into several (fiber or copper) links as long as the "shared" link provides sufficient bandwidth for all simultaneous video streams. The required bandwidth for each camera depends on the video quality and the used video codec.

Unless you require some kind of routing, a layer-3 switch is not required. If you need to separate access to the cameras, a dedicated subnet behind a routing firewall or a layer-3 switch with ACLs is recommended.

If a sufficient number of cameras is deployed within a 100 m radius you can use a PoE switch with fiber uplink. 802.3at PoE supports up to 25.5 W at the powered device (PD). Other options include a PoE injector for each PoE-capable camera or separate power on location.

Comment: Sir all  the IP cameras ,NVR should be in a separate LAN or subnet so that people from the prexisting Intranet or LAN cannot access the cameras or the NVR cannot be accessed without logging in with user name password by select authorized personnel like visting webpage in the Internet with a mandatory signin and the IP HD cameras are to be located at various geographical locations mutually at 500 to 1km  to 1.5 Km distance.Please advice in view of this.The pre-exsisting  intranet has a Cisco 2960 series switch where single mode 12 core OFC comes from different  500 to 1km  to 1.5 Km distance

Comment: Sir I have edited the question and desribed my concept of the plan and I am seeking from this platform advice words of wisdom from you and other editors if the is right/wrong or what corrections are needed.No specifications are requested Please ignore those as they stand withdrawn.I want your guidance from the conceptual angle.

Comment: So please lift the hold Sir and please answer me because I will be using only these items with some modifications as per your answer in a hypothetical test case scenario to do a sort of thought experiment

Comment: @stacklooker You should bring your question(s) in a readable form. As is, nobody is fond of wading through that mass. Also, you need to limit them to the core questions, we can't explain the world to you. Do keep in mind that asking for opinions is off-topic here. And please re-read my answer as I've actually answered most of your questions already. If you are totally clueless you should consider hiring a pro.

Comment: I am asking if my scheme in the last three paras just above your comment is workable/write or wrong in the described hypothetical situation.Is there any correction or modification to be made in this plan and are you advising me to edit and rewrite the question to know if my plan is workable as a solution to the hypothetical scenario described before the I will rewrite the part I have written to so as to remove the ambiguity keeping all the points that was done for re-framing the question by the learned editors here because I want to get answer to my question

Comment: I have some some confusion regarding the practical utility of using 12 core single mode OFC in this scenario.I figured that 4 core single mode OS2 OFC will be suffice for this purpose2 for data transmission &reception & 2 redunndant. I also found that since complete isolation camera network is intended so why not have 2 NIC cards in the desired client computers and 4 core single mode OS2 OFC link between each client location and the NVRWhile viewing intranet 1 NIC will be activated

Comment: and for came purpose the other NIC will be enabled, no layer 3 switch should be there and for each camera and client there will be two unmanaged network switch with requisite fabric metric will be there.If possible there may be only 1 NIC just for camera management and/or viewing so from these computers the Intranet will not be available, for  each client and camera the unmanaged network switch will just have minimum no of ports but sufficient bandwidth/throughput handling capacity and there will nolayer 3 switch between the existing intranet and Ip camera LAN which will have  separate switch